# Как сохранить файл в python с указанным именем

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Пытаюсь сохранить фото с названием в котором присутствует `//`, у меня не получается так как python расценивает это как путь к папке а не как название файла, что в таком случае можно сделать? И как сохранить картинку или какой-либо другой файл с названием `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Comment: Выполнить замену `/` на какой-нибудь другой символ

Comment: Разве // может быть в имени файла?

Comment: невозможно использовать `/` в имени файла включая расширение и в окнах и в пингвинах... нельзя